# Is there an analogue to folium.LatLngPopup() in plotly?

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-python, folium

While making a map.html using plotly from python3, with added points and lines, i would like to add a feature to be able to click on any other point (other than the extra data i am representing) and get a pop-up with the lat+long of that other point.

Like what you get with folium when you do:

```
map.add_child(folium.LatLngPopup())
```

Is there a way to do this?